# Can the Actionbar be behind the NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Is it possible (and how?) to have a navigation drawer in front of the actionbar+contents? I've been pondering my head on how this is implemented in the google maps app.

Comment: Note that what the Maps app does violates the Android design guidelines (http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html), probably because their approach predated those guidelines. I doubt that they are using `DrawerLayout`, but rather created something themselves. You could use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to get a better idea.

Comment: @CommonsWare Why am I not surprised that you're the first to reply! Anyway, Thanks! They've just updated the googlemaps api (now with map padding) and it's just irresistible not to use the actionbar in overlay mode. But, the actionbar draws in front of the navdrawer, so I guess you can't have them all huh. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: "They've just updated the googlemaps api (now with map padding)" -- yeah, it looks pretty nice. I'll be experimenting with that tomorrow. "it's just irresistible not to use the actionbar in overlay mode" -- um, well, have you tried actually resisting? :-) "But, the actionbar draws in front of the navdrawer" -- poke around and you may find recipes specifically for `DrawerLayout` and an overlay action bar.